# How to connect php rest api to fake backend of angular js multi user login system?

Tags: angular, api, authentication, angular-fullstack

I installed angular login project from  here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-role-based-authorization-example. I am trying to connect fakebackend to a real php mysql rest api. How to do that?

fake-backend.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, mergeMap, materialize, dematerialize } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User, Role } from '../_models';

const users: User[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    uuid: 'jsdfvuuid',
    username: 'admin',
    psd: 'admin',
    email:'somethis@getMaxListeners.com',
    adminapprove:'1',
    role: Role.Admin,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    uuid: 'jsdfvuuid',
    username: 'user',
    psd: 'user',
    email:'usersomethis@getMaxListeners.com',
    adminapprove:'1',
    role: Role.User,
  }
];


@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const { url, method, headers, body } = request;

        // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
        return of(null)
            .pipe(mergeMap(handleRoute))
            .pipe(materialize()) // call materialize and dematerialize to ensure delay even if an error is thrown (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/648)
            .pipe(delay(500))
            .pipe(dematerialize());

        function handleRoute() {
            switch (true) {
                case url.endsWith('/users/authenticate') && method === 'POST':
                    return authenticate();
                case url.endsWith('/users') && method === 'GET':
                    return getUsers();
                case url.match(/\/users\/\d+$/) && method === 'GET':
                    return getUserById();
                default:
                    // pass through any requests not handled above
                    return next.handle(request);
            }

        }

        // route functions

        function authenticate() {
            const { username, password } = body;
            const user = users.find(x => x.username === username && x.psd === password);
            if (!user) return error('Username or password is incorrect');
            return ok({
              id: user.id,
              username: user.username,
              psd: user.psd,
              email: user.email,
              uuid: user.uuid,
              role: user.role,
              token: `fake-jwt-token.${user.id}`,
            });
        }
```

I am getting all users information in app.component.ts file using rest api call. but in this fake-backend, I don't know how to get users array from rest api or app component. Please help.

I am thinking if I replace below static array (const users: User[])  with dynamic data, fakebackend will  get data from real database.

in short

**I want know how to get data to users array that is in fake-backend.ts showd below from rest api or app.component.ts**

```
const users: User[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    uuid: 'jsdfvuuid',
    username: 'admin',
    psd: 'admin',
    email:'somethis@getMaxListeners.com',
    adminapprove:'1',
    role: Role.Admin,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    uuid: 'jsdfvuuid',
    username: 'user',
    psd: 'user',
    email:'usersomethis@getMaxListeners.com',
    adminapprove:'1',
    role: Role.User,
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have working fine, starting from your own code, **the way to get to the faked users from your *app.component.ts* page**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-role-based-authorization-example-2zwebp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**I am going to explain the steps to achieve it**:

- First, you need to inject the HttpClient servive to its constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private http: HttpClient
  )
```

- Then, inside that constructor add the call to a new 'getUsers()' method (only if the logged user is an admin):

```
 this.authenticationService.user.subscribe((x) => {
      this.user = x;

      if (this.isAdmin) {
        this.getUsers();
      }

    });
```

- Finally, you have to add a new variable *users* and the new method in your app.component.ts code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  user: User;
  users: User[];
...


...
  getUsers() {
    this.authenticationService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
      this.users = users; // <== From this point, you have access to all the faked users
      console.log('Faked Users: ', this.users );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I am getting the users data in app.component.ts from rest api. I want to get that data in fake-backend.ts file to check with the user authentication function. but Problem here is fake-backend.ts file is not a component. so I dont know how to pass data from component file to fakebackend.ts file.